# WSO2. How to get the value of the tag xml of the coded escape characters?

Tags: xslt, wso2, mediator, wso2-esb

Good day!

The client sends to the proxy server, SOAP message Xml encoded coded escape characters. How to get value from the Xml?

Example. SOAP request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetPhone xmlns="http://ProxyService">
      <xml>&lt;xml&gt;&lt;phone&gt;8888888888&lt;/phone&gt;&lt;/xml&gt;</xml>
    </GetPhone>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to get a phone number and send it to the XSLT mediator.

Here is my proxy service:

```
<inSequence>
  <script language="js">mc.setPayloadXML(new XML(mc.getPayloadXML()..*::xml.toXMLString()));</script>
  <property xmlns:ns="http://ProxyService"
            name="phoneValue"
            expression="//ns:xml/ns:phone"
            scope="default"
            type="STRING"/>
  <log level="custom">
    <property name="logValue" expression="get-property('phoneValue')"/>
  </log>
  <xslt key="in_xslt">
    <property name="phone" expression="get-property('phoneValue')"/>
  </xslt>
  <log level="full"/>
  <send>
    <endpoint>
      <address uri="http://localhost:322/"/>
    </endpoint>
  </send>
</inSequence>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace toXMLString with toString :

```
<script language="js">mc.setPayloadXML(new XML(mc.getPayloadXML()..*::xml.toString()));</script>
```